# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Models.Subcategory'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a code segment and queries like these:

```
        var sub = db.Subcategories.Where(s => s.SubcategoryName == sid).FirstOrDefault();
        var businesses = db.Businesses.Where(b => b.StateID == rvm.StateID && b.Subcategories.Contains(sub));

        if (businesses == null)
        {
            return View("NoBusinessFoundInSubcategory");
        }
```

The point is that the value of `businesses` should be `null`. But when I checked in the debugger it has a value like this: `{System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Project.Models.Business>}`. And when it hits another query which is defined later in the code, which is this one:

```
var list = businesses.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(b => Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(temp) - Convert.ToInt32(b.Zip))).Take(10).ToList();
```

I get an error message saying:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Project.Models.Subcategory'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Any idea what the problem might be, and how to solve it?

Comment: *The point is that the value of businesses should be null*: No, it should never be null. As a rule of thumb any LINQ method which returns an enumerable will never return null but an empty enumerable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The point is that the value of businesses should be null. But when I checked in the debugger it has a value like this: {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery}.

That is because of deferred execution. Until you actually request any data from the query (e.g. by your `AsEnumerable()`) the query is not executed and so the error also does not show up until it is. And as pointed out by Dirk: It never will be `null`, but an `IEnumerable` with 0 items.

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Models.Subcategory'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

This tells you, that it is not supported to use methods like `Contains(sub)` on complex types. You need to do something like the following:

```
var businesses = db.Businesses.Where(b => b.StateID == rvm.StateID
             && b.Subcategories.Any(s => s.SubcategoryName == sub.SubcategoryName));
```

If you want to execute the query right away you can do this in several ways, e.g.:

1. Convert to (as you already did later in your code) or save as `IEnumerable` as only `IQueryable` supports deferred execution in this case:

   `IEnumerable<Business> businesses = db.Businesses....`
2. Call a materialization method/extension:

   `var businesses = db.Businesses.Where(...).ToList();`

**HINT:**
As you are just trying to check if the business exists this would be much faster, as it only results in one DB-query and does not materialize an entity:

```
int businesses = db.Businesses.Count(b => b.StateID == rvm.StateID
                        && b.Subcategories.Any(s => s.SubcategoryName == sid));
if (businesses <= 0)
    return View("NoBusinessFoundInSubcategory");
```